# react-router Basename also allows routes without basename

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I want my app to be served from a subdirectory , say localhost:3000/base , So that the routes page1 and page2 are served at localhost:3000/base/page1 and localhost:3000/base/page2

I tried using basename in React Router for this.

It works.

However, just localhost:3000/page1 also matches the page1 component and same for page2.

How do I prevent this from happening?

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
  return (
    <>hi
    <Router basename="/base">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/page1" render={props => <div>Hello</div>} />
        <Route path="/page2" render={props => <div>Hi</div>} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I included the react-router-dom and added to BrowserRouter basename = "/Recidiviz-site"

```
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter basename = "/Recidiviz-site">
      <App/>
  </BrowserRouter>

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution helps you base on the scenario.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes basename="/admin">
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <>
              <h1>this is home</h1> <a href="/admin/page1">Go to page1</a>{" "}
              <a href="/admin/page2">Go to page2</a>
            </>
          }
        />
        <Route path="page1" element={<a href="/admin/page2">Go to page2</a>} />
        <Route path="page2" element={<a href="/admin/page1">Go to page1</a>} />
      </Routes>
      <Routes path="/*">
        <Route element={<Navigate to="/admin" />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```